# Can't get the bot to recognize if the user reacting has a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The bot sends the `embed` and reacts to it, but I can't get it to check if the user reacting to the embed has a certain role. (Only certain roles can accept/deny the request.)

When the role ID was a role that the bot was in. It counted the bot's reactions, but when a user reacts with the correct role, it doesn't recognize it and goes to the timeout error:

> you didn't react with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.

```js
client.channels.cache.get("771101528386961428").send(embed).then(function (message) {
    message.react("")
    message.react("")

    const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && reaction.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "873477291445985330");
    };

    message.awaitReactions(filter2, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();
            if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                client.channels.cache.get("868298545269182495").send(Aembed)
            } else {
                message.author.send("Your request has been denied");
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
            message.reply('you didn\'t react with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
        });
});
```

Comment: could you post only relevant code?

Comment: I can do yes, sorry thought it was better to post the whole code but I have trimed it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageReaction) has no `.member` property, but you can use [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) instead to obtain an instance of `GuildMember` corresponding to the `user`, who reacted to the message.

```js
const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
    return ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
        message.guild.member(user).roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "role id");
};
```

Note that later in your code, you use `message.author.send()`, that won't work because in this context, the `message` is the message sent by the bot -> the author of the message is your bot. And the bot can't send a message to itself. Will throw an error like this:

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^12.5.3`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks thats working now and yes the DM thing isnt working and thanks for pointing that out and saving me pulling my hair out, also thanks for editing my post a little, not great at working these yet :)